# Get DateTime dayOfWeek/dayOfMonth as String

Tags: java, jodatime

How can I get the day of week or month as a String? Without having to do something like:

```
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();
        String dayOfWeek = null;
        switch(now.getDayOfWeek()) {
            case DateTimeConstants.MONDAY:
                dayOfWeek = "Monday";
                break;
            case DateTimeConstants.TUESDAY:
                dayOfWeek = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case DateTimeConstants.WEDNESDAY:
                dayOfWeek = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case DateTimeConstants.THURSDAY:
                dayOfWeek = "Thursday";
                break;
            case DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY:
                dayOfWeek = "Friday";
                break;
            case DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY:
                dayOfWeek = "Saturday";
                break;
            case DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY:
                dayOfWeek = "Sunday";
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 13):

Well, apparently it's just `dateTime.dayOfWeek().getAsText();` as documented [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/field/AbstractReadableInstantFieldProperty.html#getAsText%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can create DateTime extension method with the above logic and use wherever required without repeating the whole logic.

Comment: Nope, see my answer. Shoulda taken a quick look @ http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_instant.html before I asked :(